# Total Recall (1990) nail color change effect

Tags: effects, make-up, total-recall

In the first Total Recall, there's an unimportant shot where the receptioninst at Recall is changing the color of her nails. She taps one with a stylus, and it "wipes" to a different color. (I can't remember if all of them changed, or just the ones she tapped.) The effect was flawless, and this was in 1990 - way before CGI was being used! Anyone know how they did that effect?

[image]

Comment: I think if you look at [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computer_animation_in_film_and_television), you'll discover CGI had been used *extensively* before *Total Recall*. You'll remember that [Tron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) came out in 1982 and it had a BUNCH of CGI in it.

Comment: @Paulster2 In fact *Tron* was not nominated for the effects Oscar because they were "cheating", i.e. using computers to do the effects. (just a little side anecdote).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ... I didn't know that! Doesn't surprise me though.

Comment: I just noticed her nails are a couple millimeters thick! Now I wouldn't be surprised if it's a practical effect -- a mechanical device that they just glued on top of her real nails!!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Wrong. They didn't have that kind of motion tracking CGI technology in 1990. They did this by... HAND, using traditional animation techniques, not by computer.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - No clue what you're talking about because TRON was the first movie to [utilize extensive CGI](https://variety.com/2017/film/news/tron-jeff-bridges-cgi-1982-disney-anniversary-1202486941/). TRON came out in *1982*, well before the release of *Total Recall*. If you look at my comment, I'm not saying this *was* CGI, I was just stating the fact CGI had been around since before this movie. I have no clue what is "wrong" with that statement. Also the reason it is a COMMENT and not an answer. I wasn't trying to answer the question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 There's a very big difference between fullscreen computer generated imagery (like TRON, Toy Story, etc.), and computer generated imagery that augments live action footage. The second (briefly seen in Total Recall during the scanning scene) had not been used before 1990, let alone "extensively".

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Yes they are different ... however, it doesn't make what I said wrong. CGI is CGI, whether it is full screen or used to augment. It's still computer generated. It still doesn't make me "Wrong." (as you put it and still seem to think). And again, I wasn't saying it was used here, I was saying they had CGI well before this movie came out. In TRON it was used EXTENSIVELY.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 In the context of this conversion it is misleading. The question is about CGI augmenting live action footage, so comments about other types of special effects confuse what's being discussed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [**Den Of Geek - Top SFX shots**](http://www.denofgeek.com/other/12661/top-sfx-shots-no18-total-recall):

> **The nails are [rotoscoped](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/the-art-of-roto-2011/)** to provide an area for an animated colour transition to take place, and that's all there is to it.

[**Rotoscoping**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping)

> refers to the technique of manually **creating a matte for an element on a live-action plate so it may be composited over another background**

---

Some other **[examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rotoscoped_works#Live_action_films)** of **"painting" over live-action film** that predate ***'Total Recall'*** (1990):

- [**Who Framed Roger Rabbit**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096438/) *(1988)*

  [image: Benny] <sup>[[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDNzgdc69aE)]</sup>
  [image: Benny 2] <sup>[[Source](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Roger_Rabbit/Gallery)]</sup>
- Original [**Star Wars**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) trilogy *(1977-1983)*

  **Lightsabers**

  [image: 1]

  [image: 2]

  [image: 3]

  [image: 4]

  - [**Star Wars Featurette: The Birth of the Lightsaber**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIefj6dOhnM)

Comment: According to the DVD commentary (or was it a featurette?) her fingernails were actually painted their final color, and the initial color was the effect. It's a simple matter to matte out a particular color (like they do with blue and green screens), even before CGI. You matte out the color of the nails, then fill the "holes" with a new color. You don't even really need to rotoscope. The transition is animated, of course.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the rotocoping would have been done by HAND, just as it was with Star Wars and Roger Rabbit.

Answer (score 19):

CGI was actually fairly common practice by the 1990s, a watershed period for digital visual effects. Most prominently rendered in wireframe in the 1970s (Star Wars IV, 1977; Superman, 1978), by the mid-80s various scifi and fantasy films employed photoreal mapping effects (Flight of the Navigator, 1986) and were making strides in live action/digital composition and character animation (The Abyss, 1989). We tend to think of CGI in terms of photoreal humans or animals, which look dated by 2010s standards, but accepting that subtler blends of environmental digital VFX were quite common by then, and the industry's relative mastery of green or blue screen (chroma key) compositing and rotoscope animation, it's not difficult to imagine that shots like the nail color change in Total Recall were done digitally.

(The VFX team of Total Recall [won the Special Achievement Award for Visual Effects in 1990](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/awards) for groundbreaking [use of CGI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsTza718oN0) as well as an extensive mix of animatronics, stop motion and miniature set composites.)

Traditionally or digitally, the nail color change was achieved with chroma key compositing. Based on the conspicuously saturated blue/orange of the nails, it's likely the actresses's nails were painted green, making it easy to overlay any other solid color in post-production while preserving light reflection.

Comment: Probably *very bright green* :D

Comment: This is totally wrong. This a HUGE difference between full screen CG animation (as seen in Tron and Star Wars) and mixing live footage with CGI imagery. Such things did NOT exist in 1990. The "light saber" effects in Star Wars were done by HAND.

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't tell you the exact technique they would have used, but I assume they just had an effect artist colour it in post-production.

For the record, CGI was being used in film to varying degrees all throughout the 1980s, though they have said that one of the only CG shots in Total Recall was for the [x-ray scanner](http://www.pajiba.com/seriously_random_lists/mindhole-blowers-20-facts-about-total-recall-that-might-open-your-mind.php#.U1rucPldVBl) scene.

Comment: Much more succinct, I actually think this should be the main answer.

Comment: Not only was the "x-ray scanner" scene the only shot to use CG imagery, it was the FIRST Hollywood film to use CG imagery this way. And despite this, the animation was still done by hand.